# ¿Cómo refactorizar este codigo con linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo este código, y me pregunto si podría optimizarlo usando linq...si es así

¿Cómo sería?

Mi código:

```
            var saldosLetras = new List<SaldoLetraModel>();
            var saldoLetra = new SaldoLetraModel();
            foreach(var item in result.SaldoLetras)
            {
                saldoLetra.CuentaBancariaFechaSaldo = item.cuentaBancariaFechaSaldo;
                saldoLetra.CuentaBancariaSaldo = item.cuentaBancariaSaldo;
                saldoLetra.MonedaId = item.monedaId;
                saldoLetra.MonedaNombre = item.monedaNombre;
                saldosLetras.Add(saldoLetra);
            }
```

Comment: optimizarlo seria que fuera mas rapido? porque con linq, vas a lograr hacerlo en una linea.. pero no va a ser mas rapido.. ya que el linq va a hacer exactamente lo que haces vos, agregandole el overhead de los controles de tipos y cosas asi...

Comment: Por que el arquitecto de software ...quiere q sea linq  :(

Comment: Entonces la pregunta seria, me obligan a pasar este codigo a linq, alguien podria decirme como se hace? porque de optimizacion, veo poco y nada...

Comment: la clase SaldoLetraModel tiene esas 4 propiedades nada mas o tiene mas cosas?

Comment: Por las minúsculas y quizas su estructura si el tipo de result.SaldoLetras fuese el mismo o derivado de/hacia SaldoLetraModel no necesitarias el foreach. Otra; para "reducirlo" sería: saldosLetras = result.SaldoLetras.Select( s => new SaldoLetraModel(CuentaBancariaFechaSaldo = item.cuentaBancariaFechaSaldo[, las demás propiedades])).ToList()

Comment: RobertoLeOr  deberias escribirla como respuesta para que pueda ser votada y otros usuarios lo entiendan mejor ...

Comment: Deberias colocar tu consulta para pasarla a linq, porque lo unico que mostras es que recorres un foreach y llenas un List<T>, despues podes optimizar la consulta usando AsParallel();

Comment: Tengo una pregunta. Quieres sobreescribir saldoLetra? Pregunto porque veo que haces un new antes del loop y adentro del loop estas solo cambiando el mismo saldo letra.

Comment: Quiero agregar solo algunos valores a una clase  son tipos diferentes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para convertir una lista en otra distinta podrias usar linq de esta forma, usando el `select`

```
var saldosLetras = (from item in result.SaldoLetras
                    select new SaldoLetraModel(){
                                CuentaBancariaFechaSaldo = item.cuentaBancariaFechaSaldo;
                                CuentaBancariaSaldo = item.cuentaBancariaSaldo;
                                MonedaId = item.monedaId;
                                MonedaNombre = item.monedaNombre;
                            }).ToList();
```

O tambien se puede usar el metodo de extension `Select()`

```
var saldosLetras = result.SaldoLetras.Select(item = > new SaldoLetraModel(){
                                                CuentaBancariaFechaSaldo = item.cuentaBancariaFechaSaldo;
                                                CuentaBancariaSaldo = item.cuentaBancariaSaldo;
                                                MonedaId = item.monedaId;
                                                MonedaNombre = item.monedaNombre;
                                            }).ToList();
```